# Access props inside export function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I access `this.props` inside an export function?

```js
export const InactiveItem = () => (
  <span
    style={{
      borderRadius: 100,
      backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
    }}
  >
    Inactive
  </span>
);
```

When I try `{this.props.value}` my page breaks, and I also can't create a `const` to store it

Comment: just use destructuring assignment: `export const InactiveItem = ({value}) => {...}`

Comment: That's a function you shouldn't use `this` go for value instead, `this` should be used inside class components

Comment: @zb22 Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functional component, just use props instead of using `this`.

```js
export const InactiveItem = (props) => (
  <span
    style={{
      borderRadius: 100,
      backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
    }}
  >
    {props.value}
  </span>
);
```

```html
<InactiveItem value="Some Value" />
```